# I detect the process and try to terminate cmd when cmd pops up, but does not work

Tags: c, winapi

I used the Win32 API to monitor the process and try to code a program that would block cmd when it ran.  (I want to turn  off  cmd immediately when it is detected or disable it.)

But when I run it, cmd opens well (...)

What should I do? Do you have to do it the other way around?

```
while (true) {
        BOOL hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
        if (hRes == FALSE)
            break;
        if (pEntry.th32ProcessID == ::GetCurrentProcessId())
            continue;
        wchar_t* pn = pEntry.szExeFile;//I think this part may be a bit wrong but I don't know how to fix it...
        if (pn != L"cmd.exe")
            continue;
        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pEntry.th32ProcessID);
        if (hProc) {
            // 죽여버려!!!!
            if (TerminateProcess(hProc, 0)) {
                unsigned long nCode;
                GetExitCodeProcess(hProc, &nCode);
            }
            CloseHandle(hProc);
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

what should I do?
If this qestion doesn’t have enough inforamation, ask me again about that please.

Comment: Monitoring processes in a loop with the PSAPI is not a good way to handle this situation. You should instead [use a `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine()` callback](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/procmon.aspx), or [hook `NtCreateSection()`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/soviet_protector.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare strings in C you can't do this by `==`. This will compare the addresses of the strings.

Use a function of the `strcmp()`-family to compare the contents of the strings.

*N.B.: This is a big problem also in other languages, for example Java or C#.*

Comment: `if (wcscmp(pn, L"cmd.exe")!=0)`I changed it like this.... but it doesn't work...cmd can open..

Comment: What is the result of `TerminateProcess()`? Does it succeed? If not, what is the error?

Comment: Is `OpenProcess()` succeeding? `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` is way too many privileges to ask for just to call `TerminateProcess()`, all you need is `PROCESS_TERMINATE`. Also, calling `GetExitCodeProcess()` is useless since it will return the exit code you give to `TerminateProcess()`